# Custom control in a .net web application project

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have a few custom controls that were created as Server Controls projects. I had a few changes to make, so I just added the classes to an existing Web Application project so I could have things in one place. This web app project is compiled into a dll that is used on several web projects.

When I build the web app project and place the dll in the bin of a different website, when I go to use the control I get the following error:

Unknown server tag 'CustomControls:RadioButtonListForGrid'

If I add the custom control classes to the app_code folder of my website it works fine. I used the object browser and confirmed that these classes are in the dll.

Am I missing something obvious here? Do I have to leave these as Server Control projects and combine the dlls using ILmerge?

**EDIT**

Turns out that I needed to add the assembly name. It also turns out that the assembly wasn't named what I thought it was. Guess I should of checked that. Oops.

Comment: So what was the assembly name??  What was the naming pattern?

Comment: See my comment below, on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add the tag prefix to web.config?

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="CustomControls" namespace="MyApp.CustomControls" ...
```

Comment: Yes. Also tried at the page level. The same web.config setup works with the classes in the app_code folder, but not compiled in the dll.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2007/08/02/generation-of-designer-file-failed-unknown-server-tag.aspx.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I've tried with and without the assembly, in all permutations

Comment: That's very odd.  It almost sounds like a versioning problem.  I don't suppose restarting the IIS Server is an option.

Comment: Nope, restarting IIS didn't do the trick. I can get to the namespace in code, so it's there...

Comment: Well, it turns out I'm an idiot. The web app project had an assembly name that isn't the same as the company portion of <company>.<product>. For whatever reason I do need the assembly name, and it is of course important to know WHAT your assembly name is. I'll mark you as correct for your trouble!

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm it, adding assembly name in the Register directive works! So it's a must even if it's the same assembly.